# Using a JS bundler with a dummy entry point just for bundling purposes

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, webpack, esbuild

I have a legacy Java app using JS inside JSPs. We statically import JS dependencies from filesystem into our JSP files, some of them are old JS dependencies, some of them are newer and use the import/export JS feature.

**For the module-based dependencies I'd like to bundle them.** Most if not all bundlers I am familiar with, like webpack/esbuild uses an entry point to analyze the usage of dependencies and then bundles all dependencies and all app code used from entry-point onwards and puts them all in one big file

My JSP page spit JS code like so

```
<script type="module">
   // do some stuff...
   import { RFB } from 'rfb.js' // dozen of js files 
                                // referenced, that is why
                                // i want to bundle them 
                                // into just one js file...
   // do some stuff with RFB
</script>
```

Then in the a dummy entrypoint I'd like to do that same import in a separate esbuild project for the purpose of bundling the module in one js file.

**The idea is to use a dummy entry point that imports the elements I know I use in my JSP application and use that project (webpack/esbuild) for the purpose of using its bundling functionality.** However, the bundle usually has this format

```
1. (() => {
2. // - Dependencies 1, 2, N goes here
3. // - import/export statements removed.
4. //
5. // - entry-point code
6. // - app code
7. })();
```

Of course if I import this file into my JSP file I can't access the dependencies. I was thinking of doing one of these 2 things:

1. I could add in the entry-point something like: `window.ClassIAmInterested = ClassIAmInterested` then that class will be available in the global scope of my JSP page.
2. I could remove the lines 1 and 7 of the bundle and then everything would be available in the global scope.

And although either of the 2 options might work I don't fully understand the implications of doing it. I know I am trying to use the bundlers in a way they are not designed, since I explicitly want to use the entry point as a dummy code that will just import whatever I know I use in my JSP pages. So **I need clarity regarding if what I am trying to do is ok or if there is a better way of doing it.**